# How to echo only one title from $categories array

Tags: php

hope someone can help with echo only "title_2 with books1,..." from multiple titles in $categories array

example arrays:

```
$categories= array(

'title_1' => "Books", 
"books1" => array( "Books1", "set1", "type"), 
"books2" => array( "books2", "set1", "type"), 
"books3" => array( "books3", "set5", "type"),

'title_2' => "Books_2", 
"books1" => array( "Books1", "set1", "type"), 
"books2" => array( "books2", "set1", "type"), 
"books3" => array( "books3", "set5", "type"),

'title_3' => "Books_3", 
"books1" => array( "Books1", "set1", "type"), 
"books2" => array( "books2", "set1", "type"), 
"books3" => array( "books3", "set5", "type"),
,....
);
```

Thanks

Comment: More info needed. What have you tried?

Comment: this question will be closed,anyway hint to your question is print_r($categories['title_1'])

Comment: Jtheman thank you, working, haved tryed like Baba sugested (thank you Baba) but didnt echo with urls. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy ....

```
$categories= array(

'title_1' => "Books", 
"books1" => array( "Books1", "set1", "type"), 
"books2" => array( "books2", "set1", "type"), 
"books3" => array( "books3", "set5", "type"),

'title_2' => "Books_2", 
"books1" => array( "Books1", "set1", "type"), 
"books2" => array( "books2", "set1", "type"), 
"books3" => array( "books3", "set5", "type"),

'title_3' => "Books_3", 
"books1" => array( "Books1", "set1", "type"), 
"books2" => array( "books2", "set1", "type"), 
"books3" => array( "books3", "set5", "type"),

);


echo "<pre>";
echo $categories['title_2'] , "\n"  , implode(",",$categories['books1']);
```

Output

```
Books_2
Books1,set1,type
```